# Installing Tex on Spyder

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, latex, spyder

I am trying to export .pgf plots from matplotlib with Anaconda Spyder.

I understand that I need to have Latex installed in the path, so I have downloaded the Texlive Core package from Conda. However, I am still getting the following error messages in Spyder if I run the line:  `text.usetex: True`

```
kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories:
```

`` I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'! ``

Please could somebody help me install Tex correctly so that I can use it in my plots?